# Syntax babel in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, syntax-error, babeljs

Good evening. I'm having a syntax problem, I'm migrating to babel and I have the problem in the following syntax. Require an unnamed module. In the default import of nodejs I can import without naming the exported module and passing the app in, already in babel es6 I could not find something similar, but made it work.

**Node default**

> export

`router.get('/',(req, res) => res.send('test'))
 module.exports = app => app.use('/test', router)`

> require()

`require('./routes/uploader')(app)`

**Babel**

> export

`router.get('/',(req, res) => res.send('test'))
 export default app => app.use('/test', router)`

> import

`import router from './routes/uploader'
 router(app)`

**In babel I was able to perform the import only by naming and then passing the app inside the router. I researched a lot but I did not find a simpler way. Would you have a better idea to export the router by passing the app on babel?**

Comment: I'd say it's a good idea to do `const router = require('./routes/uploader'); router(app)` without Babel, too.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, I am adopting babel, but I will mix a little of each is what the node already supports or the babel, was a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require` can still be used in Babel if that's the intention.

```
import router from './routes/uploader'
router(app)
```

is the way how this is done with ES modules, considering that `router` function is `./routes/uploader` default export. It's not specific to Babel.

`router` import name is self-documenting and can be debugged in case it's not a function but something else. While `require('./routes/uploader')(app)` is a shortcut that is common in Node.js that may be difficult to read and debug.

> Would you have a better idea to export the router by passing the app on babel?

`import` statement is supposed to be statically analyzed, it doesn't contain code that should be evaluated. There's no other way to `export` it, ES module is an object, all exports are object properties, it's either `default` or named export.

Though modules can be designed to not require exports to be wrapped with a function.

It can be `app` instance that is used across the app. There should be a dedicated module for the app to avoid circular dependencies:

*app.js*

```
export default express();
```

*index.js*

```
import app from './app';
import './routes';

app.listen(...);
```

*routes.js*

```
import app from './app';

app.get(...);
```

Another way that is more popular is to decouple router from app instance. Express routes can be mounted, that's a major benefit:

*index.js*

```
import router from './routes';

const app = express();
app.use(router)
app.listen(...);
```

*route.js*

```
const router = express.Router();

router.get(...);

export default router;
```

There are cases when wrapping export with `app => { ... }` is beneficial, but it is not necessary here. Any way, it's a good convention for modules where `app` instance is really needed, e.g. to reach `app.locals`.